# Рукописи не горят

Tags: перевод

In Bulgakov's "Master and Margarita" there is the famous sentence: Рукописи не горят.

It's usually translated into English as "Manuscripts don't burn".  However it seems to me (a native English and non-native Russian speaker) that it could also be read as an impersonal construction, "People don't burn manuscripts" (Рукописи here being accusative rather than nominative).  So my questions:

- Are both translations in fact correct?
- If so, is either to be preferred?  In context, both seem sensible to me - the latter perhaps even the more poignant, being so clearly contrary to the facts of life in Bulgakov's society.

Comment: David, just warn to warn to that translations from Russian to English are off-topic.

Comment: @shabunc Sorry, didn't realise that. Is there somewhere else I can ask this sort of question?  Or, is it possible to propose that this sort of question should be on-topic? It seems to me that russian.se is the natural place to ask it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"To burn something" in Russian would be *жечь*. *Гореть* is an intransitive verb, it does not accept an object.

The phrase *рукописи не жгут* could indeed grammatically mean both "one doesn't burn manuscripts" and "manuscripts don't burn (something)", though the latter meaning is unrealistic of course.

Comment: It is incorrect.  "Рукописи не жгут" and "рукописи не горят" phrases have different meanings. The latter is an idiom. You can't replace it with the former.

Comment: @JFSebastian: what exactly is incorrect?

Comment: Do you understand that both are true: "рукописи жгут" and "рукописи не горят" (using the meaning from the book)? And therefore it is incorrect to use "не жгут" instead of "не горят" here, see [my answer](http://russian.stackexchange.com/a/8642/348).

Comment: @JFSebastian: where exactly in my answer did I say they were the same?

Comment: Why do you mention "рукописи не жгут" if its translation is unrelated to "рукописи не горят"? It is misleading at best

Comment: @JFSebastian: because the English verb "to burn" is ambitransitive and corresponds to two different Russian verbs, which was the root of OP's confusion. I believed it would do good for the answer to mention both Russian verbs.

Answer (score 5):

> ― Простите, не поверю, ― ответил Воланд, ― этого быть не может. 
>   **Рукописи не горят.**
>
> "Forgive me, but I don't believe you," Woland replied, "that cannot
>   be:  **manuscripts don't burn.**"

The precise meaning `Рукописи не горят` is **`Рукописи are non-inflammable, incombustible.`**

How can we say the same thing using poetic phraseology in English?

The question will be answered.

Answer (score 3):

"Рукописи не горят" idiom means  "you can't kill an idea" or (sometimes)  "art is immortal."

It has nothing to do with "рукописи не жгут" -- the Master says that *he burned it* only a couple of paragraphs above in the original text.
Therefore the second translation is wrong.

The mere fact that it is an idiom means that the phrase should not be interpreted literally.

Comment: Do you mean that this was an idiom existing before Bulgakov used it?  If so can you give any references?

Comment: @David: No. I don't think it is existed before Bulgakov. Though there are similar sayings: "что написано пером—не вырубишь топором" и (slightly different meaning) "слово не воробей, вылетит—не поймаешь" that might have existed before (I don't know). The point being that it should **not** be read as "people don't burn manuscripts" because they do but manuscripts survive anyway (it may be the blessing and the curse).

Comment: It seems that my suggested translation is wrong for grammatical reasons, see other answers.   However I can't agree that it doesn't make sense.  The novel has a large component of satire in it, and it is easy to imagine Bulgakov writing "people don't burn manuscripts" in the clear knowledge that they actually do.

Comment: Also IMO the Master did burn his manuscript exactly as he said, but Woland with his extraordinary/supernatural powers was able to "resurrect" it.

Comment: @David Maybe an example would help to illustrate the difference: "people had  killed Jesus" (he did die) vs. "Jesus can't die" (God is immortal) and "Master had burned manuscript" (he did) vs. "manuscripts don't burn" (art is immortal). Your translation is inappropriate here

Comment: There is no difficulty, I understand what you are saying and I accept that my suggestion is wrong (though I think @quassnoi has given the best explanation).  However I don't agree when you say that my translation **must** be wrong because people do burn manuscripts.  The fact that something is written down in a novel doesn't make it true! ;-)

Comment: @David  The translation *must* reflect the meaning suggested by the novel. Though your translation is wrong even if we ignore the novel:  you can't use "жечь" instead of "гореть" here and quassnoi's answer is *wrong*. Read my comments there.